# UITableViewCell reusability doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[UITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buiUs.png)
UITableViewCell reusability doesn't work. The cells are not refreshing their content while scrolling the page. Instead of it, the new image is put upon the old one. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (ChartCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ChartCell *cell = (ChartCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"graphCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString* object_id = dataDict[@"cellIDs"][indexPath.row];
   [[NetworkManager sharedSource] getData:[object_id integerValue] Success:^(NSDictionary *data) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       cell.cellID  = [data[@"chartType"] integerValue];
       //cell.textLabel.text = data[@"chartType"];
        switch (cell.cellID) {
            case 0:
                for(int i=0; i<[data[@"chartData"] count]; i++){
                    cell.barNames[i] = data[@"chartData"][i][@"name"];
                    cell.barHeights[i] = data[@"chartData"][i][@"value"];
                }
                [cell createPieChart];
                break;
            case 1:

                for(int i=0; i<[data[@"chartData"] count]; i++){
                    cell.barNames[i] = data[@"chartData"][i][@"name"];
                    cell.barHeights[i] = data[@"chartData"][i][@"value"];
                }
               [cell createBarChart];
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


    });
} Error:^(NSString *errorMessage) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //показать ошибку
    });
}];

   return cell;}
```

**UPDATE!!!**
 So prepareForReuse really works. But isn't it against MVC - writing code for dynamic tableview cell in UITableViewCell subclass? Shouldn't I create a View Controller for my custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Without code, it's clearly hard to say.

Comment: "the new image is put upon the old one" - sounds like reuse is working properly. Every time the cell is on screen, it reuses an old one (which has an image) and then calls your function, which adds an image. If this isn't what you want, then you need to remove the old image in `prepareForReuse` or change your `cellForRow` function to just modify subviews, not add new ones.

Comment: And what does `[cell createBarChart];`? Is there call to `addSubView:` inside it? Also, what's the code for `prepareForReuse`. Clearly, the reusability is working, the issue is that you misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

In `ChartCell class`, use `prepareForReuse()` method to clear your cell

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    // clear pie chart
    // clear bar chart
    // clear name etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are reusing the view. So if you added a view to the cell's View once, it will be there. You have to remove the view from superview and get ready to show the another cell's data.

You can clear the existing views by overriding `prepareForReuse` method in `UITableViewCell` class.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
   [self clearPieChart];
   [self clearBarChart];
}
```